# Window always on top within application

Tags: c#, winforms

to make my winforms window to always stay on top I can use:

```
TopMost = true;
```

But that will make the window always stay on top. I want it to only stay on top within the application. So when I minimize my application or change application I dont want it to stay on top anymore.

Comment: Have you tried making the window modal?

Comment: Yes, but, the I cant use my application as I want because the focus is only is on the new window. I only want the window on top but be able to use my application in the background as usual.

Comment: So, is it some kind of toolbox, something like that? It's very unclear what the use case is here.

Comment: @Cyrix I see. That is an interesting requirement.

Comment: The requirements are actually 1. Not modal 2. Always on top within application. :P

Comment: Do you have an example of another program that uses the same concept?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are seeking for [Form.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) property

> To make a form owned by another form, assign its Owner property a reference to the form that will be the owner.
>
> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the owner form. For example, consider a form named Form2 that is owned by a form named Form1. If Form1 is closed or minimized, Form2 is also closed or hidden.Owned forms are also never displayed behind their owner form. You can use owned forms for windows such as find and replace windows, which should not disappear when the owner form is selected.

In case you are not showing the child form from the "application window", the easiest way to have access to the application window (a.k.a main form) is to use something like this

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(MainForm = new MyAppForm());
    }
    public static MyAppForm MainForm { get; private set; }
}
```

and then

```
var childForm = new MyChildForm();
childForm.Owner = Program.MainWindow;
//childForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
childForm.Show();
```

Comment: I think you are right. I was just reading about it: http://www.csharp-examples.net/topmost-form/ Thanks, il try that now! :)

Comment: I will accept this answer because this solves the problem exactly as I asked for. But its very ugly to keep a reference of mainform in this big application. But il try to solve this in a nice way. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, perfect! I actually solved it by using childForm.Owner = ParentForm. Worked fine also. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `TopMost = true;` make your form a dialogue by using `Form1.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Would be great except I cant use my application as I want. I want to use my application as usual though Iv created new windows thats always gonna be on top.